# angular 2 Import Custom Module returns error

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-modules

I'm getting this error trying to import a custom module

> zone.js:269 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]'
>   imported by the module 'AppModule'

this is my app.module.ts

```
const SELFBITSCONFIG = {...}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    ...
    SelfbitsAngularModule.forRoot(SELFBITSCONFIG)
  ]
})
```

this is the external file i'm trying to import

```
@NgModule({
    providers:SELFBITS_PROVIDERS,
    imports:[HttpModule]
})

export class SelfbitsAngularModule{
    static forRoot(config:SelfbitsAppConfig):ModuleWithProviders{
        return {
            ngModule:SelfbitsAngularModule,
            providers:[
                { provide: SELFBITS_CONFIG, useValue: config }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using angular 2 starter webpack by Angular Class, currently running "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22"

Comment: Can you fill more info about your modules? what are behind `SELFBITS_PROVIDERS`